# Ionic: err: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, serve

When I try to run this command:

*ionic serve --cordova --platform browser*

I got this error msg:

Error: spawn UNKNOWN

at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at spawn
(C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\node_modules@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:170:12)
at Subprocess.spawn
(C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\node_modules@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:143:16)
at Shell.spawn (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\lib\shell.js:151:24)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawn (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:363:19)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawnWrapper (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:339:20)
at async AngularServeCLI.serve (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:329:9)
at async AngularServeRunner.serveProject
(C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli\lib\project\angular\serve.js:117:9)

What is the problem?

Comment: why are you using `--cordova` and `--platform` arguments??

Comment: Because my app work right only with this command. But if I use ionic serve commad I got this message too.

Comment: run command `ionic info` and add ouput to your question.

Answer (score 1):

run `npm start` instead of `ionic serve`.

Worked for me !